# Pushstate adding new param,how prevent this?

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I have a problem, I have a tabs with pushstate:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '#/' + $(this).attr('href').substring(1));
```

And when I want to change this pushstate with:

```
  function updateUrl() {
    history.pushState(null, null, `${location.href}/?page=` + this.page);
  }
```

And when I click to pagination buttons. I get link like this: `http://example.com/foo/bar/#revs/?page=1/?page=2/?page3`

```
<button onclick="updateUrl(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="updateUrl(2)">2</button>
```

But I need change only param `page`. How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `location.href` just adds up on the current link. 
Construct the link using:

```
location.origin + location.pathname + location.hash.split('/')[0] + '/?page=' + this.page
```

---

Learn more about [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object.

You can always access `location` object in browser's console to understand its structure.

Comment: now this removes `#revs` and link is: `http://example.com/foo/bar/?page=1`. How I can save `#revs`?

Comment: Now I have problem how In my question :)

Comment: Okay, right! Then you should make sure to get only `#ref` part. Updated my answer.